# Identifying the sequence $1,2,4,8,16,23,28,38,49,62,70, \ldots$, in which increasing a term by the sum of its digits yields the next term

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> The number $1$ is written on a blackboard. After every minute the number written on the blackboard is increased by the sum of its digits. The first few numbers, therefore, will be
> $$1,2,4,8, 16,23,28,38,49,62,70, \ldots$$
> Prove that at some point of time $2011$ will be written on board.

I am actually trying to find a particular rule in those numbers but failed to find any such. Somehow, I observed that if I get $1991$ in the sequence, then $2011$ will be the next number. But can't guarantee the existence of $1991$ in this sequence.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sequence is https://oeis.org/A004207; its b-file https://oeis.org/A004207/b004207.txt does not contain $2010$.

Comment: How are you getting 23 after 16 ???

Comment: @trueblueanil $23 = 16 + 1 + 6$

Comment: I feel like it must be relevant that modulo $9$, the sequence repeats $1,2,4,8,7,5$ over and over.

Answer (score 1):

As Greg pointed out in the comment, the digit sum sequence you have mod 9 is equivalent to the repeat of $1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 5, \dots$.
If you apply the 'digit-sum' operator to the added number repeatedly, you can make the sequence $1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 5, \dots$.
For instance, from $1991$ to $2021$, you add $20$ (the digit sum of $20$ itself is $2$). From $2011$, you add $4$, from $2015$, you add $8$, and so $2, 4, 8, \dots$ the next added part will have digit sum $7$, $5$, and so on...

The sequence is listed at https://oeis.org/A004207.
In fact, you can find the existence of $2011$ from the table at https://oeis.org/A004207/b004207.txt.

I don't think there exists a closed-form solution to find the $n$th number in this sequence. You may write a code to generate the sequence and check the existence of $2011$ which will not take long.